# How to show error message for invalid JOptionPane input?

Tags: java

My current JoptionPane dialog requires an integer type input. How do I show an error message if the input isn't an integer and it loops back to the input dialog?

Here's the partial code reffering to said problem.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    //MOUSE CLICK DETAILS
    if (e.getSource() == jlabelthepian) {
        String name = "The Pian";
        double price = 8.50;
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Qty"));
        double total = price * qty;
        model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        model.addRow(new Object[]{
            name,
            price,
            qty,
            total,}
        );
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
            sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
        }
        jtxtgrand.setText(Double.toString(sum));
```

Comment: wrap the inputdialog logic in a `while(true)`, wrap the parseint in a try/catch. at the end of the try break out of the while loop, in the catch show an erro r with JOptionPane

Comment: I got it to work now. That was extremely helpful. Thank you very much. Cheers mate.